# Namespace issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function name is mixed even if I am using a namespace. In the below example when I call  `nwFunc.callMe()` or `$.Test1.callTest()` it will execute `_testFunction()` of `doOneThing`. I am expected for `$.Test1.callTest()` to call `_testFunction()` in `$.Test1` API instead of one in `doOneThing`. What I need to do to correct it?

Example:

```
var doOneThing = function() {
    _testFunction= function() {
        ...
    }

    return {
         // public 
         callMe: function(){
        _testFunction();
         }
    }
}

var nwFunc = doOneThing();
nwFunc.callMe();
$.Test1.callTest();
```

### below is a example API

```
jQuery.Test1 = (function(){

    _testFunction= function() {
        ...// do differently
    }


    return {
        // public
        callTest: function(){
            _testFunction()
        }
    }
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: Oops, now that I spot your actual issue (haven't read the question properly) I'll have to mark it as a duplicate of [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not in an object literal, you are in a function body.

> ```
> _testFunction: function() {
>     .... // do differently
> }
> ```

is not an object property, but an anonymous function expression preceded by a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label?) and is immidiately forgotten as it is not assigned anywhere. Make it a simple function declaration instead:

```
function _testFunction() {
    .... // do differently
}
```

---

And

> ```
> return {
>      // public 
>      callMe() {
>          _testFunction();
>      }
> }
> ```

is just a syntax error, in here you need the [object literal sytnax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers):

```
return {
    // public
    callTest: function() {
        _testFunction()
    }
};
```

or

```
return {
    // public
    callTest: _testFunction // exporting the function directly
};
```

---

> When I call `nwFunc.callMe()` or `$.Test1.callTest()` it will execute `_testFunction()` of `doOneThing`. What I need to do to correct it?

You have to use a [`var` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to put your `_testFunction` variable in a local scope. Currently you're writing to the global scope, where only one `_testFunction` exists (currently in `doOneThing` you're overwriting the `_testFunction` from `jQuery.Test1`, and both `callTest` functions will invoke the new one). A function *declaration* would've fixed this as well (using the local scope), it [is similar to a var statement + function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572).

Comment: I corrected the syntax errors. I think both _testFunction = function(){...} and function _testFunction(){..} are same.

Comment: @user1595858: Unfortunately they're not…

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up your syntax slightly.  You are using object literal notation when you declare the function originally and using function declaration notation when actually creating the object, so you should switch the two:

```
jQuery.Test1 = (function(){

    function _testFunction() {
        .... // do differently
    }

    return {
        // public
        callTest: _testFunction
    }
}(jQuery))
```